# How to add a QPixmap to QGraphicsView that is static?

Tags: pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

hope someone of you can help me. I have a QGraphicsView, that is displaying a jpeg. The jpeg is much bigger than the QGraphicsView, so you can drag the jpeg (with the mouse). Over that jpeg I want to add a QPixmap. But this QPixmap needs to be static. If I move the jpeg, the QPixmap needs to always on the same position. With a QLabel that has only text, it isn't a problem. But if I set a QPixmap to the QLabel, it isn't displayed. How can I solve my problem? 
Does anyone have an idea?

Best, 
Oli

Answer (score 0):

You may try to subclass *QGraphicsScene* and reimplement *drawBackground* method to display your static QPixmap.